# How to log quartz and nhibernate in different log files using log4net

Tags: nhibernate, log4net, quartz.net, log4net-configuration

I use in my application nhibernate and qurtz and I would like the log4net to write the logs to different files. the nhibernate logs to "nhibernate.log" and the qurtz logs to "quartz.log".

How do I need to cinfigure the log4net config file to get this result??

Thanks, Avi.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure which appender the nhibernate logger has to use:

```
<logger name="NHibernate">
   <level value="ERROR" />
   <appender-ref ref="NHibernateAppender"/>
 </logger>

<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
   <level value="ERROR" />
   <appender-ref ref="NHibernateAppender"/>
 </logger>
```

Configure a different appender for your other loggers and you have sepparate log files.